# C# Method which may execute any code in the loop

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

For example if i have to type something like that multiple time, is there any way to put this loop in the method with parameters like `LoopMethod(Code lines, int count)`

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            code line 1;
            code line 2;
            ...
            code line N;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            code line 1;
            code line 2;
            ...
            code line N;
        }
```

if result to have something like that.

```
LoopMethod{
            code line 1,
            code line 2,
            ...
            code line N,
            1000
}
```

Comment: delegates, Func, Action. Pick your poison

Comment: Could you provide some examples with Func, Action ?

Comment: *IF* you are familiar with lambda functions (think: LINQ), I'd recommend browsing the source code for LINQBridge (http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/downloads/detail?name=LinqBridge-1.1.cs). For a primer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Comment: You're welcome. If you're new to the type of syntax used in LINQ, try to use it a lot in some projects and be patient with the process -- it's a different way of thinking and could take a bit to wrap your head around but practice is the key. At least, that's how I was finally able to internalize it. YMMV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generic form would be to first create an extension method:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach(var currentItem in enumerable)
        {
            action(currentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Then using that you can do the following:

```
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ForEach(i =>
                                              {
                                                  Console.WriteLine(i);
                                              });
```

Which would iterate from 0 to 999 (use 1001 as the second param for inclusive).  The added benefit is that this then works on any enumerable type.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variant:

```
public static LoopMethod(int iterations, Action<int> body)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        body(i);
}
```

You'd call it like this:

```
LoopMethod(100, i =>
{
    code line;
    code line;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do that with delegates rather easily:

```
public static void LoopMethod(Action loopCode, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; ++i) loopCode();
}

public static void Main()
{
    LoopMethod(() => {
        code line 1;
        code line 2;
        code line 3;
    }, 100);
}
```

You can alter that any way you like, even changing it to `Action<int>` which takes as a parameter the current loop counter. See @Gabe's answer for the `Action<int>` variant :)

Of course, I have to wonder why you want to reproduce such an obviously built-in construct like looping?

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda expression like this:

```
LoopMethod(() => {code line 1; code line 2;}, 100);
```

The method declaration would look something like

```
void LoopMethod (Action code, int count) {
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         code();
     }
}
```

There may be odd syntactical error there ( I haven't tested it), but the approach should work.